# standardize Vaadin form widths in Vaadin 14 Java API

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I notice that when I use LoginForm it has a default size.  I can't quite figure out how it gets this size.  I would like to standardize the sizes of all my forms, e.g. FormLayout and LoginForm.  I do not mind making my FormLayouts match the size of the LoginForm -or- set the LoginForm and FormLayouts to my own preset size.  The problem is that when I set the LoginForm's width as a percentage, it never seems to match the same size as the FormLayouts... the LoginForm always comes out smaller for the same percentage.

Is there any way to set my LoginForms and FormLayouts to have the same width consistently?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there does not seem to be a way how to get the fields from a LoginForm with the Java API. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/issues/53) for a similar issue.

As described in the issue, you could execute JavaScript to get the relevant element. Then, you could modify its CSS manually. To set the width of a LoginForm, you could use `vaadin-login-form-wrapper`.

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-login-form-wrapper')[0].style.width = '200px';");
```

Alternatively, you could use raw CSS and change the attributes of this element.

After investigating the CSS, you could find out that the width of the form is defined by the CSS variable `--lumo-size-m`. The max-width of the `vaadin-login-form-wraper` is defined by `calc(var(--lumo-size-m) * 10)`. Therefore, you could also change the theme or just get the width from there and use it for your FormLayouts.